# New activity required just to display a new screen?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to create in-app Help screens for my Android app.  The Help activity is created by the user selecting Help from the options menu.  The first screen displays a list of Help categories.

When a user clicks on a category I want them to be taken to a new screen that displays details about the category.

I want the Back buttons functionality to be maintained and I know (I think!) it will work well if I have a new activity for each category's details.

**But**, is having an activity for each subcategory overkill?

Answer (score 3):

Why not have one activity that displays subcategories, SubCategoryActivity. When you start this activity pass in an extra letting it know which subcategory to display (an int or a string).

If the UI of all these categories are all very different from each other this may not work well.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an overkill, unless you really want the neat animation on activity change. `FrameLayout` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a Dialog instead of an activity for subcategories? If not, go for sgarman's solution. Create one "HelpActivity" that you pass contents of the help in as extras when you launch the intent.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do, if you want to reuse the same activity is : 1) create one activity(Say HelpActivity) and design its layout like textview, button etc., but not set the textview value.

2) For all categories in your HELP category list, call the HelpActivity every time.

3) Check for the calling activity using this code:  Create an interface and declare activity constant for all activities separately like:

public interface ActivityConstants {

```
 public static final int callingACTIVITY1 = 1001;
 public static final int callingACTIVITY2 = 1002;
 public static final int callingACTIVITY3 = 1003;
```

}
 // then identify calling activity

int callingActivity=getIntent().getIntExtra("calling-activity", 0);

```
    switch(callingActivity)
    {
    case ActivityConstants.callingACTIVITY1:

        // do your stuff here
                    // set textview value based on callingACTIVITY1  
        break;
```

so on...

3) if you want to got back to calling activity after user has read the help instructions, then use 
super.onBackPressed(); //this will take you back to your calling activity.

Hope this will helpful to you.